# Is it possible to make a join query with Prisma without a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, next.js, prisma, prisma-graphql, prisma2

I've been struggling with this for a while but with no success.

I have two tables that **might** have a relation but not necessarily.

```
FIRST
+----+-----------+------------+
| ID | LPR       | TIMESTAMP  |
+----+-----------+------------+
| 1  | QWE123RTY | 05-05-2020 |
+----+-----------+------------+
| 2  | ZXC789IOP | 05-05-2020 |
+----+-----------+------------+
| 3  | ASD567FGH | 05-05-2020 |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

```
SECOND
+----+-----------+------------+----------+
| ID | LPR       | TIMESTAMP  | OWNER_ID |
+----+-----------+------------+----------+
| 1  | AAA111BBB | 04-05-2020 | 3        |
+----+-----------+------------+----------+
| 2  | QWE123RTY | 02-05-2020 | 1        |
+----+-----------+------------+----------+
| 3  | BBB222CCC | 14-05-2020 | 1        |
+----+-----------+------------+----------+
```

I basically want to replicate `SELECT * FROM FIRST JOIN SECOND WHERE LPR="QWE123RTY"` in prisma but to no avail. I cannot use a foreign key (at least to my knowledge) since the foreign key in SECOND might not always be present in FIRST as vice-versa.

An alternative that I think might work is to run two separate queries where I retrieve the matching records in SECOND and then run

```
prisma.FIRST.findMany({
    where: {
        LPR: { in: ['QWE123RTY', 'BBB222CCC'] }
    }
})
```

Has anyone actually managed to do something like that?

Comment: Did you read the manual specifically for full joins in mysql https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/mysql/reading-and-querying-data/joining-tables NB you don't need foreign keys to join tables..

Comment: I forgot to specify that I wanted to use the PrismaClient to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem, by using `prisma.$queryRaw` which I actually didn't know it existed for the few months I've been using it and only stumbled upon it now.
Here's the documentation link for reference: [Prisma - Raw database access](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access)

The end solution was:

```
await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM FIRST JOIN SECOND ON FIRST.LPR=SECOND.LPR`
```

P.S. The only issue I ran into by using the `queryRaw` method instead of the regular Prisma Client was that the BLOB type values are retrieved as strings, instead of as a Buffer, but that can be handled both on the front-end as well as in the back-end accordingly with minor modifications to the response.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, will update it promptly.